# linux command grep -is "abc" filename|wc -l

Tags: linux, command

what does the s mean there and also when pipe into wc what is that for? I know it eventually count the number of abc appeared in file filename, but not sure about the option s for and also pipe to wc mean

```
linux command grep -is "abc" filename|wc -l
```

output

```
    47
```

Comment: man would have gotten you there in way under a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `man` page has everything you would want to know about the options for grep:

```
   -s, --no-messages
          Suppress  error  messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
          Portability note: unlike GNU grep, traditional grep did not con-
          form to POSIX.2, because traditional grep lacked a -q option and
          its -s option behaved like GNU grep's -q option.  Shell  scripts
          intended to be portable to traditional grep should avoid both -q
          and -s and should redirect output to /dev/null instead.
```

The pipe to `wc -l` is what gives you the count of how many lines the string "abc" appeared on.  It isn't necessarily the number of times the string appeared in the file since one line with multiple occurrences is going to be counted as only 1.

Comment: this really clear and helps, (I checked the man page before i posted the question, was still confused after read man page), thanks Mark!

Comment: if i took -l away, just like grep -is "abc" filename|wc, then it returned 3 number such as 47 167 285, then what that 167 and 285 mean? (i know 47 means)

Comment: @maggieqq: Number of lines, number of words, number of characters.

Comment: i figure out what 167 and 285 means but still a bit confused about man page said 47 is the newline, 167 is the words and 287 means bytes, so 47 lines has abc in it? and 167 is how many times abc appeared in the file filename, is that accurate?

Comment: @maggieqq: No.  There were a total of 167 words on lines that had abc on them.  Remove the pipe to `wc` and perhaps it will be a bit more clear.

Comment: i don't think i get it, how do i count the number of occurances of "abc" in the file filename even if it appears more than 1 time in a line?

Comment: @maggieqq: Not tested, but off the top of my head: `sed -e "s/abc/abc\n/g" test.txt | grep -c "abc"`

Comment: whoa, that is complicated, if grep...|wc -l can count the line which contain the word abc, then isn't there an easy way (don't have to be grep ...|wc) to count a word appearing in a file for total appearance of a word?

Answer (score 2):

-s means "suppress error messages about unreadable files" and the pipe to wc means "take the output and send it to the wc -l command" which effectively counts the number of lines matched. You can accomplish the same with the -c option to grep: grep -isc "abc" filename

Answer (score 2):

Consider,

command_1 | command_2

Role of the pipe is that- it takes output of command written before it (command_1 here) and supplies that output to the command written after it (command_2 here).

Answer (score 0):

grep man page says:

```
-s, --no-messages         suppress error messages
```

`grep` returns the lines that have `abc` (case insensitive) in them. You pipe them to `wc` to get a count of the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

From `man grep`:

> ```
>    -s, --no-messages
>           Suppress  error  messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
> ```

The wc command counts line, words and characters. With -l it returns the number of lines.